# What happen if I power the Raspberry with both the USB and external power voltage simultaneously?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, power-supply, usb-power

I'm newbie on Raspberry pi. I just want to know, What happen if I power the Raspberry with both the **USB** and **external** power voltage simultaneously? Would this burn the controller?

Comment: You cannot power with USB. Actually your questions is vague; your idea of what things are called does not correspond to any official documentation.

Comment: I have read the two power sources will "fight" and may cause damage to the Pi powers supply.  I suggest you avoid the situation if possible.  Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Milliways The assertion that you can't power over USB is somewhat at odds with conventional wisdom. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Assuming *USB* means the micro USB power socket, what is *external power voltage*?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I assume the question is referring to powering via the microUSB socket and the 5V and ground pins of the expansion header.

Comment: @goobering The Pi cannot be powered via the USB ports (unless you have already powered it - due to a bug in the circuitry). This question has been given more attention than it deserves, we could guess any of the 100 things the OP is planning and answer them all!